# sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.1 on raspberry pi - Internal Error (os_linux_zero.cpp:254)

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I used sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2 but wanted to upgrade to the current release sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.1

here is some sample code

```
public boolean open() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:sqlite:%s",
                databasefile));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Datenbankdatei '" + databasefile
            + "' wurde erfolgreich geöffnet");
    return true;
}
private void initConnection() {
    if (!new File(databasefile).exists()) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        return;
    }
    con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

If I execute this program, it needs 180mb of memory(seen via top -p )

now I want to upgrade to a newer release of the sqlite-jdbc from [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads).
I can start it on my Ubuntu x64 but on raspberry I get "a fatal Error"

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_linux_zero.cpp:254), pid=9134, tid=3060774000
#  fatal error: caught unhandled signal 4
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-    b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Zero VM (25.45-b02 interpreted mode linux-arm )
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/flex/core or core.9134
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/flex/hs_err_pid9134.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

But the mentioned core dump was not created!

any ideas what the problem may be?

I'm using arch linux on an raspberry Pi B